# How to click on specific text in a paragraph?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a paragraph element as follows:

```
<p>You have logged in successfully. <em>LOGOUT</em></p>
```

Clicking on "LOGOUT" will initiate a logout procedure (e.g display a confirmation prompt).

How do I simulate this clicking on "LOGOUT" using Selenium WebDriver?

Answer (score 0):

To find and click the "LOGOUT" text with python, you can use the following code:

```
logout = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//em[text()='LOGOUT']")
logout.click()
```

Answer (score -1):

This could help :
[Execute button Click with Selenium](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/selenium-click-button-with-examples/)

As a preach :
You should first, try to analize the general basic components offered for your tool, and the interactions with external systems (selection, executions, listening).

Based on the first link offered as a resource your code should be some like :

```java
package postBlo; 
import org.openqa.selenium.By; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.chromse.ChromeDriver; 

public class singleClickButton {
    public singleClickButton() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./exefiles/chromedriver.exe"); 

        WebDriver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        driver.manage().window().maximixe(); 
        driver.get("your-local-site-to-test"); 

        //Referen an input component and set a values
        driver.findElement(By.name("id-html-tag")).sendKeys("someValue text");


        /* ## Execution of button by using id
            You could use both methods to identify the element you need : 
            By using "xpath" expression wich allows you to navigate between elements by using expressions
            By using id-identifier

            Chose one of both. 
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("expression-xpath")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("id-element")).click();
        */
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/elemnts-container-button/button\r\n" + "")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("button-id")).click();
    }

}
```

As a mention I'm not related to Selenium but still the logic it's alike.
Best